# I can't find the format file `Latex.fmt'!

Tags: installing, format-files

I have just migrated to MacBook Pro running El Capitan after years on MS Windows. I happily ran Tex on Windows. I have installed MacTex and tried to typeset a sample document. I get the following messages:

```
"This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=Latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt Latex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /Users/Jeremy1/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: Disabled formats: 10
mktexfmt [INFO]: Not selected formats: 46
I can't find the format file `Latex.fmt'!"
```

I have read a number of Q&As on this site but none gives a solution to my problem.

Comment: I can reproduce the error if I call, from a terminal window, `Latex test`, which is wrong. What are you using for running LaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in windows and solved it using TeX Live Manager. I don't know if the Mac version also has this but I am sure even if it doesn't have the GUI, you can do the same thing from the command line. Here are the steps:

1. Run TeX Live Manager
2. Go to Actions menu
3. Click "Rebuild all formats"

What this actually does is (from what I understand) to just run `fmtutil-sys --all`